# Forming my ERD, couple of issues with it

Tags: mysql, erd

[image: My ERD]

[image: Description of the company]

Okay, my partners and myself created these a while ago. We are going to be transferring this into SQL through Visual Basic soon, but I want to make sure everything is ready to go. Two major complaints that we were not able to fix was...

**"By having Transaction and Product directly connected you are unable to allow multiple products on the same order (customer can't order both a latte and cappuccino on the same order)."
"Membership table: Not sure what the data in DiscountTypeTotal means - do you have multiple pieces of data in the same field? (then your table isn't on 1NF).**

***It looks like you need to allow each member to have multiple discounts - so you need another table to capture that."***

How do we effectively correct these? How else would we connect Transaction with Products? I understand that the customer can only purchase one item per transactions, so would we have products and another table for multiple items? Allowing multiple customers to have discounts, I am lost. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you explain the relationships between `Customer`, `Membership`, and `Discount`.

Comment: @commanderZiltoid No, that would mean each product can only be sold once. The solution is to add a many-to-many relationship table between Products and Transaction.

Comment: What is the DiscountTypeTotal field for?

Comment: @reaanb you are absolutely correct. Don't know how I didn't see that.